# How to make a datatable with crossfilter2 from dimension with arrays?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have data like this:

| IDX | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack,Mike,Amy |
| 2 | Amy,Mike |
| 3 | Amy |
| 4 | Jack,Rachel |

And with crossfilter2, I've been able to make a pie chart of each individual and the number of times they are listed like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.5.4/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.2.7/dc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pie_chart = new dc.PieChart("#pie-chart");
    d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(data) {
        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        var nameDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.Name.split(",");});
        var nameGroup = nameDim.group();
        pie_chart
          .dimension(nameDim)
          .group(nameGroup);
        pie_chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

Which makes the pie chart just the way I want it. Jack, Mike, Amy, and Rachel each get their own slices and Amy's is the biggest with 3.

But when I try to make a datatable showing that same data, I'm lost. Using the same dimension as the pie chart just gets me the comma separated strings instead of each individual separately.

```
var table = new dc.DataTable("#table");
table
  .width(500)
  .height(200)
  .dimension(nameDim)
  .columns(["Name"]);
table.render();
```

How do I get the table to look like below:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 3 |
| Jack | 2 |
| Mike | 2 |
| Rachel | 1 |

EDIT:

Here is the solution that gave me the table I wanted in the end.

```
<div id="pie-chart"></div>
<div id="table" class="table"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.5.4/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.2.7/dc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [{
        "IDX": 1,
        "Author": "Jack|Mike|Amy"
    }, {
        "IDX": 2,
        "Author": "Amy|Mike"
    }, {
        "IDX": 3,
        "Author": "Amy"
    }, {
        "IDX": 4,
        "Author": "Jack|Rachel"
    }, ]

    var pie_chart = new dc.PieChart("#pie-chart");
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);
    var nameDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.Author.split("|");
    }, true);
    var nameGroup = nameDim.group();

    pie_chart
        .dimension(nameDim)
        .group(nameGroup);
    pie_chart.render();

    var table = new dc.DataTable("#table");
    table
        .width(500)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(reversible_group(nameGroup))
        .columns([function(d) {
                return d.key
            },
            function(d) {
                return d.value
            }
        ])
        .order(d3.descending);

    table.render();


    function reversible_group(group) {
        return {
            top: function(N) {
                return group.top(N);
            },
            bottom: function(N) {
                return group.top(Infinity).slice(-N).reverse();
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Right, by default the data table was designed to be used with the rows of source data from the dimension, unlike the other charts which were designed for use with aggregated groups. However, you can also [use a group as the source data for a data table](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html). Please look at this example and see if it helps, and edit your question if you can’t figure it out (or post an answer if you do!)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have seen that before and I can't figure it out :-/. I'm guessing the magic is in the reduceAdd, reduceRemove, ReduceInitial functions?

Comment: That shouldn’t be necessary. The secret is just passing a group to the `.dimension()` method, and change the data table columns to pick up the `key` and `value` fields. If you only want two columns then that’s all you should need to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I got it figured out! I'll edit my answer to show the new code.

Comment: Great, please post your answer below!